# Gathering JavaScript memory profile data from users

Tags: javascript, profiling

I'm writing a client-heavy site. Since my own testing will only get me so far, I'd like to gather some statistics on how it's performing in the wild.

I'm imagining adding some sort of profiling code to my app which will run some percentage of the time (so it doesn't slow everyone down) and sending that info home.

Adding some timing benchmarks should be easy, but what really becomes a problem with long-running pages with lots of JS is memory usage. Is there a way to instrument the memory used by my app from normal, unprivileged JS code in any of the major browsers? Are there any other good profiling metrics that are available?

Comment: great question, im sure there are some ways, not sure if cross browser though but ill see what i can find :)

Comment: Have a look at this: http://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/chrome-developer-tools-put-javascript.html particularly the section about the performance.memory propperty. As i said it's browser specific and atm i didn't find anything that works on most browsers and i doubt you will but hey chrome users are the most right?

Comment: chorme has the "inspect element" thing, that brings you to the javascript cpu profiling.... I don't know if it's the thing you are searching for. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/profiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome:

```
for (var key in performance.memory) {
    alert(key+': '+performance.memory[key]);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/usuXV/1/

Sample output:

```
jsHeapSizeLimit: 1620000000
usedJSHeapSize: 10000000
totalJSHeapSize: 16100000
```

You can also use `console.memory`. Seems to return the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Google I/O video.  It discusses JavaScript memory usage in depth and also how the gmail team observed memory usage for some of their users.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9Jlu_h_Lyw

Answer (score 0):

It would tricky to measure the memory. The new navigation timing API looks interesting regarding this but at the moment only Chrome has implemented a memory object

- Specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/
- Walk-through article(2011): http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/
- Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing